# Why won't my code take multiple inputs after asking to print the value of length and breadth?

Tags: c++, c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <conio.h> // Non-standard and not required!

int main()
{
   float areaoc,areaor,peroc,peror,l,b,r,pi;
   pi=3.14;

   printf("Enter the length and breadth of rectangle: ");
   scanf("%.2f %.2f",&l,&b);

   printf("Enter the radius of circle: ");
   scanf("%.2f",&r);

   areaor=l*b;
   peror=2*(l+b);
   areaoc=pi*r*r;
   peroc=2*pi*r;

   printf("the area of rectangle is: %.2f ",areaor);
   printf("the perimeter of rectangle is: %.2f ",peror);
   printf("the area of circle is: %.2f ",areaoc);
   printf("the perimeter of circle is: %.2f ",peroc);

   return 0;
}
```

Why does it let me enter only one value then show the result?

Comment: It works when `scanf("%f %f"..` is used instead of `scanf("%.2f %.2f"..`. Also, if you are using GCC `conio.h` won't work, and compilation error will be thrown, so you can remove it. See [this](http://ideone.com/dzZq8Q)

Comment: I have formatted your code block to be more readable, changed the title for better impact, and corrected the tags.

Comment: Gotcha ,it was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the scanf() statement so:

```
scanf("%f %f",&l,&b);
```

Then you should be able to store the 2 input values into the two given float variables, here l(length) and b(breadth).

Make the specifying state of how many number should be shown after the floating point, only on the printf statement(s).

Comment: thats good it helped me ,now i understood s,also can you please explain why?